# How to g-edit the Libreoffice Calc desktop file?

Tags: command-line, libreoffice, gedit

I am trying to change the icons of programs. Calc, firefox, and files (3 of them?).

I have no idea how to get the terminal names for programs, and even if I get them somehow - like `libreoffice --calc`, they don't seem to work in this instance.

When I do that code `libreoffice --calc` by itself, the program starts up, but errors pop up:

```
javaldx: Could not find a Java Runtime Environment!
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx

(soffice:8292): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_grid_attach: assertion 'GTK_IS_GRID (grid)' failed
```

I used:

```
sudo gedit /usr/local/share/applications/libreoffice --calc.desktop
```

to gedit, but the console says: "wtf is --calc.desktop". I even added the little %U at the end, like it says in the properties file, and still nothing.

Comment: Your title doesn't make sense. And the console can't possibly say "wtf is --calc.desktop". Don't use `libreoffice --calc.desktop`. Use `libreoffice-calc.desktop`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to edit a `.desktop` file and you are not sure what its name of the package is, have a look first:

```
ls /usr/share/applications
```

(there's no `/usr/local/share/applications` afaik, that's why your shell is cussing you)

You can *usually* guess from this. The one you want appears to be

```
/usr/share/applications/libreoffice-calc.desktop
```

Please make a back up copy of this file before you edit it, for example to drop a copy in your home directory:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/libreoffice-calc.desktop ~
```

Don't use `sudo gedit` as this could cause some weirdness with local config files in future. Use the `-H` switch to set home, or `sudo -i` to start a root shell...

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/applications/libreoffice-calc.desktop
```

By the way, the messages you see when you run

```
libreoffice --calc
```

are not errors - they are warnings designed to be seen by developers to help them debug for later versions. If I launch a gtk app from a shell I do something like

```
soffice MyFile 2>/dev/null &
```

to send that output straight to data nirvana.

Comment: Thank you, I got an error "(gedit:9163): Gtk-WARNING **: Calling Inhibit failed: ", but after deleting/local/, i managed to edit the file. I used the console because I couldnt save the file when i edited it manually. I suceeded now in what I wanted, but got 4x this error: ** (gedit:9218): WARNING **: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-spell-language not supported --- oops, i just noticed that i forgot the -H thingie you told me to put. Could you educate me a bit more about what happened?

Comment: @Thia those are not errors at all as I explained at the end of my answer. To understand the reason for using `-H`, see [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](//askubuntu.com/q/270006) - if you forgot, you can fix any possible problems by doing `chown $USER: $HOME` (do NOT use `sudo` and type carefully!) when you are logged in normally as your user.